# SSAS Partition -Default or Full

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssas, olap-cube, database-partitioning

We have a partition let say,

1. Log-2014,
2. Log 2015,
3. Log 2016-Jan-June,
4. Log 2016-July-Dec,
5. Log 2017-Jan-June,
6. Log 2017-July-Dec

Once the import routine started we will insert new data into the **Log** table and then be using ADMOMD.Net we will process the cube.

XMLA Process Type for Partition:

- *Log 2017-July-Dec* - **Process Full**
- All Other Partitions have **Process Default**

We are receiving new clients and getting old log data like 2015, 2016. Our import read all the data and insert into Log Table.

Does the "Process Default" work in this case for 2015, 2016 partitions?

Does this log data(2015,2016) will be merged into the correct partition once the cube has been processed?

Does the aggregation is re-calculated after processing the partition with process default type?

Thanks,

Chandru

Comment: I checked the ProcessDefault is not updating the partition data. If any new clients are updated 2016 file. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

**Process Default** will not bring updated members to your historical partition.  It reads state of the partition and its components (Data, Index) and does minimal processing to bring partition to a fully processed state. If your partition has been processed at the moment of issuing **Process Default** command, the command will do nothing.
**Process Default** is usually used in development process to bring cube changes online.

In your case **Process Full** or **Process Data** followed by **Process Index** will bring data on historical partitions.